# Querying a DownloadManager's content URI for a finished download gives status 200?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-download-manager

I'm using Android's DownloadManager to start some downloads, and retrieving their URIs when finished. They have the scheme `content://`, so I figure using ContentResolver should give me the info I need.

After running the query:

```
val query = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
```

I get a Cursor containing a bunch of correct info about the download, such as its mimetype, filepath, etc. I'm interested in checking the status of the download (mainly to see if it's been deleted), so I'm reading the `status` column.

However, it always returns 200. My first thought would be that it's an HTTP success response, and that maybe DownloadManager modeled its statuses after those, but that's not the case as [DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) has a constant value of 8. And, according to [DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#COLUMN_STATUS), the status should always be one of those constants (none of which are 200). I've gotten this on emulators for APi 26 and 23.

Am I misunderstanding how to use ContentProvider in conjuction with DownloadManager? Or, is there a better way I can ensure a previous download hasn't been deleted?

Edit: Here's the output of `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(query)` from the ContentResolver:

```
0 {
   _id=3
   entity=null
   _data=/storage/emulated/0/Download/*removed*
   mimetype=text/plain
   visibility=1
   destination=4
   control=null
   status=200
   lastmod=1505066595033
   notificationpackage=*removed*
   notificationclass=null
   total_bytes=213
   current_bytes=213
   title=*removed*
   description=*removed*
   uri=https://*removed*
   is_visible_in_downloads_ui=1
   hint=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/*removed*
   mediaprovider_uri=content://media/external/file/35
   deleted=0
   _display_name=*removed*
   _size=213
}
```

And from the DownloadManager:

```
0 {
   _id=3
   local_filename=/storage/emulated/0/Download/*removed*
   mediaprovider_uri=content://media/external/file/35
   destination=4
   title=*removed*
   description=*removed*
   uri=https://*removed*
   status=200
   hint=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/*removed*
   media_type=text/plain
   total_size=213
   last_modified_timestamp=1505066595033
   bytes_so_far=213
   allow_write=0
   local_uri=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/*removed*
   reason=placeholder
}
```

Comment: so is it `COLUMN_REASON` or `COLUMN_STATUS` ? what do you see when calling `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor()` method?

Comment: It's `COLUMN_STATUS`. I didn't know about `dumpCursor()`, thanks for that! Updated question with the output.

Comment: ok `status=200`, and whats the cursor like if you use `DownloadManager#query` method?

Comment: Updated question. The status is still 200, which is really weird.

Comment: see [this](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/DownloadManager.java#1465) - they use `CursorWrapper` - for example `public long getLong(int columnIndex)` method - line #1483 - for column COLUMN_REASON they actually read COLUMN_STATUS - so if you use `getString` you will get different data than if you use `getLong`

Comment: and for column COLUMN_STATUS they use `translateStatus()` method (line #1385) which explains everything

Comment: Looking at `translateStatus()`, shouldn't it be returning `1 << 3 = 8`?

Comment: yes it is returning `public final static int STATUS_SUCCESSFUL = 1 << 3`, this is for `case  Downloads.Impl.STATUS_SUCCESS:`

Comment: You were right! Calling `getInt()` or `getLong()` on the DownloadManager's query gives 8, even though `getString()` gives '200'. Thanks for the help. If you post an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: i have no idea why they made such a mess... watch out for irma ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I evacuated two days ago, haha.